# parsr.com - Connection can not be established

Tags: parse-platform

I use the datastore of parse.com to manage the data of my apps. I use javascript by the way. I establish my connection like this:

```
Parse.initialize("KRCjl8ZEgNIERgXcbhbh6kfsdeXReWfA9phOY1Ql","v5uW61qzYboq64zleielyi9876sx8se");

// A Collection containing all instances of category objects.
var categoryObject = Parse.Object.extend("categories");
var CategoryCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
    model: categoryObject
});

var collection = new CategoryCollection();
collection.fetch({
    success: function(categoryList) {
        alert("ok");
    },
   error: function(collection, error) {
        for(item in error) {
            alert(item +" = "+ error[item]);
        }
    }

});
```

The thing is that it worked yesterday, now when I browse to www.parse.com, it says that the certificate has expired. I think it has something to do with this issue.

Can anyone tell me please what I could do now.

Thanks,

enne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had an SSL issue this morning that caused downtime. You can read our post-mortem here: http://blog.parse.com/2012/09/10/summary-of-the-september-10-parse-service-disruption/.

The issue was resolved this morning at 8:42am and everything should be working fine now.

If you have any other issues with Parse, feel free to check out [parse.com/help](https://www.parse.com/help)

Answer (score 1):

If you hit parse.com, you'll get an expired SSL cert error. That's why the API calls aren't working, same thing happening for my app. I can't imagine this happening in a professional context, but there it is. I've sent a message to support. Strangely, my tweet didn't show up on @ParseIt.

Comment: Wow, a pro-account costs 150$, that's enormous.

Comment: Actually, for 15 million API requests a month, the pro account isn't bad. Anyway, they're now tweeting on @ParseIt that they're working on the SSL problem.

Comment: Yep, I hope this will be fixed asap, since I need to present my app today. Do you know if this happens more often?

Answer (score -1):

Same thing is happening for me.  I don't think is your code - probably a problem on their site.  Hopefully it'll get resolved soon.

Answer (score -1):

Parse.com is still a buggy system but you can access your data through web interface like

https://www.parse.com/apps/ispect/collections#class/

Mention you  and can access to your data.